# Symfony2 2x many-to-one in form missing form data

Tags: forms, symfony, doctrine-orm, many-to-many

I am using a Doctrine 2x one-to-many linking table like what is recommended in the [docs](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-unidirectional)

My Doctrine relationships seem to be fetching data properly, as evidenced by the fact that vars.data.myCollectionName has values,

```
{{ ladybug_dump( bandVacancyAssociation.bandVacancy.vars.data.genres) }}
```

yet when I try to access the form field children in order to use the form_row twig function my data is always an empty array

```
{{ ladybug_dump(edit_form.bandVacancyAssociations.children[0].children)}}
```

Since I do have values I can reverse engineer the symfony form structure but I would rather get it working using the built-in form widgets, any assistance would be much appreciated.

Here is the relevant code

**Band**

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="BandVacancyAssociation", mappedBy="band", cascade={"persist"})
 */
private $bandVacancyAssociations;
```

**BandType**

```
$builder
        ->add('name')
        ->add('description')
        ->add('bandVacancyAssociations','collection',
            array(
                'by_reference' => true,
                'type' => new BandVacancyAssociationType()
            )
        )
```

**BandVacancy**

```
/** 
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="BandVacancyAssociation", mappedBy="bandVacancy",fetch="EAGER")
 */
private $bandVacancyAssociations;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Genre", inversedBy="bandVacancies",fetch="EAGER")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="bandvacancy_genre",
 *   joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="bandvacancy_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *   inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="genre_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 * )
 */
protected $genres;


/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Instrument", inversedBy="bandVacancies",fetch="EAGER")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="bandvacancy_instrument",
 *   joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="bandvacancy_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *   inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="instrument_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 * )
 */
protected $instruments;
```

**BandVacancyType**

```
$builder->add('genres', 'entity', array(
        'multiple' => true,
        'expanded' => true,
        'class' => 'ZE\BABundle\Entity\Genre',
        'property' => 'name',
    ))
        ->add('instruments', 'entity', array(
            'multiple' => true,
            'expanded' => true,
            'class' => 'ZE\BABundle\Entity\Instrument',
            'property' => 'name',
        ));
```

**Band Vacancy Association**

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="BandVacancy", inversedBy="bandVacancyAssociations",fetch="EAGER")
 */
private $bandVacancy;
```

**BandVacancyAssociationType**

```
$builder
        ->add('bandVacancy', 'entity', array( 'class' =>  'ZE\BABundle\Entity\BandVacancy'))
    ;
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the one thing I was missing was this:

```
 /**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('bandVacancy', new BandVacancyType())
    ;
}
```

I can now loop through the values in the form.

```
<div class="panel">Band Vacancies
    {% for bandVacancyAssociation in edit_form.bandVacancyAssociations %}
        {#{{ dump(bandVacancyAssociation.vars.data.id) }}#}
        <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
            <div class="panel panel-default" id="panel{{ bandVacancyAssociation.vars.data.id }}">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse{{ bandVacancyAssociation.vars.data.id }}"
                           href="#collapse{{ bandVacancyAssociation.vars.data.id }}">
                            {{ bandVacancyAssociation.vars.data.bandVacancy.name}}
                        </a>
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapse{{ bandVacancyAssociation.vars.data.id }}" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        {{ form_label(bandVacancyAssociation.bandVacancy.name) }}
                        {{ form_widget(bandVacancyAssociation.bandVacancy.name) }}
                        {{ form_label(bandVacancyAssociation.bandVacancy.comment) }}
                        {{ form_widget(bandVacancyAssociation.bandVacancy.comment) }}

                        {% for genre in bandVacancyAssociation.bandVacancy.genres %}
                            {{ form_label(genre) }}{{ form_widget(genre) }}
                        {% endfor %}
                        {% for instrument in bandVacancyAssociation.bandVacancy.instruments %}
                            {{ form_label(instrument) }}{{ form_widget(instrument) }}
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Thanks to whoever downvoted this question.